# How to save specific data object to core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I could not find a way to save a specific data to core data, and leaving the rest of created objects unsaved.

For Example:

```
let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
            let trip1 = Trip(context: context)
            let trip2 = Trip(context: context)
            PersistenceController.shared.save()
```

The code block above will save trip1 and trip2 all together into the database.
But how could I only save trip1, leaving trip2 unsaved?

Comment: Create them using different contexts., then you can save then separately.

Comment: @lorem ipsum, thanks! It sounds like a good idea. I can't understand why core data not allows to save selected objects, but save all created objects.

Comment: The objects are irrelevant it saving the changes to the context.

Comment: @lorem ipsum, So the context is kinda like the selector?Using contexts to distinguish different scenes? This concept is beyond my understanding now. I need to do more research on it later.

Comment: Scenes is a good analogy. Not quite but it paints a decent picture. You are saving the scene.